# Vue.js 3 - Error while using Vue I18n plugin in vue - Cannot set property '_vm' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-i18n

I've just started working with Vue.js and learning it through some online code snippet and tutorials. I'm trying to implement internationalization support for my vue project, but I'm getting error in web-console.

Here are my code snippets

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import router from './router/index'

function loadLocaleMessages () {
    const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
    const messages = {}
    locales.keys().forEach(key => {
        const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
        if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
            const locale = matched[1]
            messages[locale] = locales(key)
        }
    })
   return messages
}

const i18n = VueI18n({
    locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
    fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
    messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})


const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(i18n);
app.mount('#app');
```

Here is my **HelliI18n.vue** file where I want to use translation

```
<template>
    hello
    <p>{{ $t('hello') }}</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'HelloI18n'
    }
</script>
```

Following code is from my **package.json** file (for versions)

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.22.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~1.0.1"
},
```

When I run my project, I see following **error** on web console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_vm' of undefined
at VueI18n (vue-i18n.esm.js?a925:1173)
at eval (main.js?56d7:19)
at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1167)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at Object.1 (app.js:1228)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
at app.js:994
at app.js:997
```

Anything I'm doing wrong here ? any dependency I'm missing ? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I believe `require.context` is asynchronous and when you are trying to construct the `VueI18n` object then the value is not resolved immediately, can you store the value of `loadLocaleMessages()` before constructing the object of `VueI18n`

Comment: No it didn't work. I even tried to give direct values for message.

Comment: Can you make an example of the above in [`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: `require.context` is synchronous....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should install [`vue-i18n@next`](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next) which is compatible with Vue 3:

```
 npm install --save vue-i18n@next
```

or via using yarn

```
yarn add vue-i18n@next
```

**Basic usage :**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: "ja",
 globalInjection: true,
  messages: {
    en: {
      message: {
        language: "English",
        greeting: "Hello !"
      }
    },
    ar: {
      message: {
        language: "العربية",
        greeting: "السلام عليكم"
      }
    },
    es: {
      message: {
        language: "Español",
        greeting: "Hola !"
      }
    }
  }
});

createApp(App).use(i18n).mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="lang">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="ar">العربية</option>
      <option value="es">Español</option>
    </select>

    <h2>{{ $t("message.greeting", {}, { locale: lang }) }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lang: "en",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**[EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-noether-998kw)**

In composition API (`setup`) :

```
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
...

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const { t } = useI18n();
      // then use it like t('message.greeting')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe `"vue-i18n": "^8.22.1"` ([git](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n)) you are using is not compatible with Vue 3 due to a major changes how Vue 3 works with regards to plugins (not very clear from the readme for sure). You can try [vue-i18n-next](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next) which is Vue 3 "ready" but still in beta stage....

Also, when using v8.x with Vue 2, be sure to create instance with `new` keyword -  `const i18n = new VueI18n()` (it's a class)

...if you are new to Vue, it would be probably better for you to work with Vue 2. Vue 3 is pretty new (released few days ago) and most of the ecosystem (all sorts of plugins and component libraries) is not ready for it yet. And you probably don't need all the new stuff. Start with v2, enjoy it's stable ecosystem and lots of learning resources on the internet and switch to v3 when all the tools you need make transition to v3 ....