# cannot add vue-i18n plugin on vue3 project

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

on a new Vue3 project made with the CLI tool, using the **Default Vue3 Preview** i end up with an error when i try to setup the i18n plugin.

```
Vue CLI v4.5.9
 > Default (Vue 3 Preview) ([Vue 3] babel, eslint)
```

i added the plugin with the vue cli, letting all the default options and get the error:

> ERROR  Error: You cannot call "get" on a collection with no paths.
> Instead, check the "length" property first to verify at least 1 path
> exists.

this is the full stdout

```
➜  hello-vue3 git:(master) vue add i18n    
  Installing vue-cli-plugin-i18n...

yarn add v1.16.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.


success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 10 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ vue-cli-plugin-i18n@1.0.1
info All dependencies
├─ cli-table3@0.5.1
├─ colors@1.4.0
├─ deepmerge@4.2.2
├─ dot-object@1.9.0
├─ esm@3.2.25
├─ flat@5.0.2
├─ is-valid-glob@1.0.0
├─ vue-cli-plugin-i18n@1.0.1
├─ vue-i18n-extract@1.0.2
└─ vue-i18n@8.22.2
Done in 8.81s.
✔  Successfully installed plugin: vue-cli-plugin-i18n

? The locale of project localization. en
? The fallback locale of project localization. en
? The directory where store localization messages of project. It's stored under `src` directory. locales
? Enable locale messages in Single file components ? No

  Invoking generator for vue-cli-plugin-i18n...
 ERROR  Error: You cannot call "get" on a collection with no paths. Instead, check the "length" property first to verify at least 1 path exists.
Error: You cannot call "get" on a collection with no paths. Instead, check the "length" property first to verify at least 1 path exists.
    at Collection.get (/home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/jscodeshift/src/Collection.js:213:13)
    at injectOptions (/home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/codemods/injectOptions.js:15:6)
    at runTransformation (/home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-codemod/dist/src/run-transformation.js:61:17)
    at /home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:290:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.resolveFiles (/home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:276:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Generator.generate (/home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:175:5)
    at async runGenerator (/home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/invoke.js:111:3)
    at async invoke (/home/tykayn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/invoke.js:92:3)
```

i use node 14.15.1 with nvm.

and here is my package json:

```
{
  "name": "hello-vue3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64631506/8172857